# Javascript not showing up on template in django

Tags: javascript, python, django, django-models, django-templates

I do not understand why my javascript files are not being applied on my templates. Here is my base.html:

```
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Project</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"  href="{% static 'css/styles.css' %}" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="{% static 'css/style.css' %}">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="{% static 'assets/css/main.css' %}">
    
</head>
<body>
    <div>
        {% include "navbar.html" %}
        {% block content %}  
        {% endblock content %}
    </div>
    {% include "scripts.html" %}
</body>
</html>
```

Here is my scripts.html:

```
{% load static %}

<script src="{% static 'js/main.js' %}"></script>
<script src="{% static 'assets/js/jquery.min.js' %}"></script>
<script src="{% static 'assets/js/jquery.dropotron.min.js' %}"></script>
<script src="{% static 'assets/js/browser.min.js' %}"></script>
<script src="{% static 'assets/js/breakpoints.min.js' %}"></script>
<script src="{% static 'assets/js/util.js' %}"></script>
<script src="{% static 'assets/js/main.js' %}"></script>
```

However, they don't seem to affect the template. For example, the dropdown menu is in a weird format if I run the server. Another weird thing happening is that `Main.js` keeps being printed on the console. I believe this was initially because of the main.js file which had:

```
console.log("Main.js");
```

However, even though I change it to the following:

```
console.log("Something new for the console");
```

I still get `Main.js` printed out on the console. Moreover, if I put `console.log("something")` for my other javascript files referenced above, they don't get printed out on the console. I have no idea why this is happneing. Thanks, and please ask any questions.

Comment: did you added static root in setting.py file

Comment: yes, I have. I have the code `STATIC_ROOT = "static_root"`

Comment: ```STATIC_ROOT=os.path.join(BASE_DIR,'assests')```
did you added this line to static_root bassically this will give the path to store your static file where you want

Comment: I really recommend @bichanna's answer. I just had the same issue as you and got it right.

Comment: @VishalPandey I tried it, but my drop down menu is not working. Still, the console.log is being printed out fine now.

Comment: yes which means your you are providing js by wrong path can you just add your settings .py static_root line here

Answer (score 0):

Clean up cached images and files!

If you are using Chrome, you can follow the following steps:

1. go to setting
2. click on privacy security
3. click on clear browsing data
4. check 'Cached images and files'
5. click on 'Clear data'

Comment: yeah... no luck. My drop down menu is still broken.

Comment: Then, the problem is in your code. Please provide the code.